# JavaScript Table filter doesn't look for numbers

Tags: javascript, html

i wanna filter dynamically based on content, and it works for the first 2 columns but not for the third.

Not sure about the Javascript might need a bit extra?

Here is my Snippet:

```
`https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD3GYTW0WBUK`
```

Here is my html:

```
<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Table</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

here is my JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here is my CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question.

Comment: a) your fiddle doesn't work at all, and b) when a) is fixed, it only works for the name column, not the first two columns as you claim and c) you can post a "working snippet" in your question rather than just code fragments :p

Answer (score 4):

In your js, you say

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
```

With that, you test the content in tr[i] (every tr), but only in td[0], which happens to be the first column. So this script does exactly what you wrote here. You will have to iterate through all the tds in each tr as well to have this work as expected.